# Accept pointer/iterator in generic function

Tags: c++, iterator, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdvector

I need to make a generic function which will allocate an array that has same elements as vector in the main function.

This generic function should accept pointers/iterators to the beginning and end of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <vector>
template <typename type> 
type *MakeArray(type::iterator start, type::iterator after_end) {
  int n = 0;
  while (start < after_end) {
    start++;
    n++;
  }
  start -= n;
  type *arr = nullptr;
  arr = new type[n];
  throw std::bad_alloc("Not enough memory!");
  while (start < after_end) {
    *arr = *start;
    start++;
    arr++;
  }
  delete[] arr;
  arr-=n;
  return arr;
}

int main() {
  int n=5;
  std::vector<double>a{1,2,3,4,5};
  double *arr = nullptr;
  try {
    arr = MakeArray(a.begin(),a.end());
  } catch (std::bad_alloc e) {
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what();
  }
  delete[] arr;

  return 0;
}
```

ERRORS:

line 5:

> expected ‘)’ before ‘after_end’

> expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token

line 30:

> missing template arguments before ‘(’ token

I don't see any reason why should I get these errors. Could you help me to fix my code? Iterators and dynamic allocation are new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *iterator type* itself as the template arguments and then extract the underlying type of the contained elements in the function.

Also, you shouldn't be using `delete[] arr;` in your function because: (a) at that point, it no longer points to the memory allocated by the `new` call; (b) if you do, you won't be able to use it in the calling module.

There are also some significant other simplifications and improvements you can make to your function, which I have shown in the below code:

```cpp
template <typename it_type>
auto* MakeArray(it_type start, it_type after_end)
{
    using basetype = typename std::decay< decltype(*start) >::type; // Type of contained objects
    size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(start, after_end)); // Quick calculation of size
    basetype* arr = new basetype[size]; // This will automatically throw (bad_alloc) if it fails
    std::copy(start, after_end, arr); // Quicker/easier way to do the data copy
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Of course, if you only ever want to copy the entire vector, you could just pass that vector itself (by reference) and use the `.begin()` and `.size()` members. But the shown code should work for any range/sub-range of a vector (or even other container type), given the relevant iterators.

Comment: thank you very much, could you edit your code for custom bad_alloc message? I need to set custom message for bad_alloc but when I try to add custom I get error `no matching function for call to ‘std::bad_alloc`

Comment: @codproe You could do that in a `try ... catch (const std::bad_alloc& e)` block in your calling (`main`) function. [Example on cppreference.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) Or you could put that in `MakeArray` and then `return nullptr;` at the end of the `catch`.